# how to set 'WaitTimeSeconds' in mulesoft sqs receive request

Tags: amazon-web-services, mule, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, mule-component

We have SQS implementation in our Mulesoft code.
As per suggestion for better code practices as mentioned below is AWS SQS docmentation.

> the WaitTimeSeconds parameter of the ReceiveMessage action, a value
>   set between 1 and 20 has priority over any value set for the queue
>   attribute ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds.

We have set ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds is SQS queue to 20 sec but we are not sure where can we set the WaitTimeSeconds parameter of the ReceiveMessage action.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you've already set queue attribute `ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds` to 20 second then you don't need to pass `WaitTimeSeconds` to `ReceiveMessage` action unless you want to override default 20 seconds. `ReceiveMessage` will still perform *long-polling* without `WaitTimeSeconds` because you've already defined it in the Queue attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Athar khan, but more query, how do I verify the long polling?, whether polling is happening after 20 secs or before.